# TASM 8086 output issue

Tags: assembly, intel, x86-16, tasm

```
xor ax,ax
xor dx,dx
mov ax,prima
mov dl,al
mov ah,2
int 21h
```

The variable 'prima' has stored 33h and it should print "3", but it doesn't, it prints "0" if I run the program normally. What bugs me is that I'm using DOSBox for debugging and if I press to see the output it displays "3" (and the register panel shows that `AL` is 33h) as it should.
Has anyone encountered this problem before? The code calculates pi.

```
data segment
            s0 db 25 dup(0ah), 'pi=  $'
            s1 db 2 dup(0ah), ' $'
            n dw 0                 
            z dw 0               
            r dw 0           
            o dw 0
            j dw 0                  
            x dw 0                  
            y dw 0
            xp dw 0                 
            yp dw 0
            rp dw 0
            cp dw 0            
            l db 0
            css dw 0
            patru dw 0
            pi dw 0
            prima dw 0
            adoua dw 0
            atreia dw 0
            data ends

            assume cs:code, ds:data
            code segment
            start:
            mov ax,data
            mov ds,ax

            mov n,93
            mov z,10
            mov r,50
            mov o,1000
            mov j,1
            mov ax,n
            mov x,ax
            mov l,0
            mov css,56
            mov patru,4

        .for:

            cmp j,1
            jne .if1                

                mov ax,x            
                mul x
                mov x,ax

                cmp x,1000          
                    ja .nrbununu      
                    mov ax,x        
                    mul z
                    mov x,ax
                    .nrbununu:

                mov ax,x             ; x=x%1000/10
                xor dx,dx   
                div o
                mov ax,dx
                xor dx,dx
                div z
                mov x,ax             ;

                mov y,ax             ; y=x;
                inc j            

            .if1:



            cmp j,2
            jne .if2               

                mov ax,y            
                mul y
                mov y,ax

                cmp y,1000          
                    ja .nrbundoi       
                    mov ax,y         
                    mul z
                    mov y,ax
                    .nrbundoi:

                mov ax,y             ; y=y%1000/10
                xor dx,dx   
                div o
                mov ax,dx
                xor dx,dx
                div z
                mov y,ax             ;


                mov ax,x            
                mul x
                mov xp,ax
                mov ax,y
                mul y
                mov yp,ax
                mov ax,r
                mul r
                mov rp,ax           ;

                mov ax,xp
                add ax,yp

                cmp ax, rp
                ja .contor
                    inc bl

                .contor:
                mov j,1

            .if2:


        inc cx
        cmp cx,56
        jnle .forx
        jmp .for
        .forx:

        mov ax,bx
        mul patru
        xor dx,dx
        div css
        mov prima,ax
        add prima,48
        mov ax,dx
        mul z
        div css
        mov adoua,ax
        add adoua,48
        mov ax,dx
        mul z
        div css
        mov atreia,ax
        add atreia,48

        mov dx, offset s0
        mov ah,9
        int 21h

        xor ax,ax
        xor dx,dx
        mov ax,prima
        mov dl,al
        mov ah,2
        int 21h

        mov dl,2ch
        mov ah,2
        int 21h

        xor ax,ax
        xor dx,dx
        mov ax,adoua
        mov dl,al
        mov ah,2
        int 21h

        xor ax,ax
        xor dx,dx
        mov ax,atreia
        mov dl,al
        mov ah,2
        int 21h





        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
        code ends
        end start
```

Comment: I think we need to see the code where prim gets assigned. My TASM is rusty but I'm not sure if "prim" directly loads the value or the "address" either, you should check that too (in case if it's `[prim]` or `word ptr prim` etc)

Comment: just checked it on my TASM (version v5.0), both `mov ax, prim` and `mov ax,[prim]` load prim's value

Comment: btw: what's all those `xor ax,ax` and are `xor dx,dx` for?? they're unneeded, if you load those registers with values 2 instructions later anyways

Comment: those were my attempts to remedy the problem

Comment: "it prints 0 if I run the program normally". Does this mean running it from the DOSBOX command prompt?

Comment: "s0 db 25 dup(0ah), 'pi=  $'" This sequence of linefeeds could throw off some emulators. Don't use it on EMU8086 where I've seen a 25 row screen just showing the first 24 rows. Have you tried printing the result without prepending this message?

Answer (score 0):

The first time you use `CX` is `inc cx`. You had assumed that `CX` is 0 at start. Indeed, the debugger sets it to 0. However, the assumption is wrong. Initialize `CX` right before `.for` with `xor cx,cx`.

BTW: Don't forget to define a stack:

```
_STACK SEGMENT PARA STACK 'STACK'
    dw  1024 dup (?)
_STACK ENDS
```